# cannot set Default route for MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I cannot set the Default Route for my MVC project. When I run the project, it goes to the address http://localhost:7555/ and it give the "HTTP ERROR 404" but if I enter the url http://localhost:7555/Default , it goes to the Default page. But I want users to go the Default page even if they dont enter http://localhost:7555/Default.

here is my Route in Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{Filtre}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

what am I supposed to do?

Comment: `Default` is a **Controller** or an **Action**, because you said "Default page"?

Comment: I have DefaultController and Action name is Index

Comment: You have other routes registered there, i think one route interfere with another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you want this functionality you would have a `HomeController` that just works out of the box with the route config. You've chosen instead to have `DefaultController` instead - so we need to work it a little differently:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{action}/{Filtre}", 
    new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ No worries