# Setting the default route for MVC site on IIS 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

I've setup a site on our webserver using IIS8.  The URL is something link ABC.mycompany.com.  When I go to ABC.mycompany.com, I get a not found error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

If I go to ABC.mycompany.com/Home/InstrumentList, it shows the the correct page I want to start on.  How do I get it to start at this route?

In Visual Studio 2013, I have Home/InstrumentList set as my start action and that works fine.  I've looked at several examples where they reference default and index pages, but my application doesn't have any of these.  Also, there are references to .aspx pages, but there are no .aspx pages in my app, just .cshtml Views and .cs Controllers.  I also have seen things about adding routes, but I'm unsure where to put them in global.asax.cs (in ApplicationStart? outside it? in a different method?  just alone?).  I also don't know what to change to work for mine (change index to InstrumentListing or leave it alone).  Nothing has worked for me so far.

Here's one of my attempts using global.asax.cs where I tried to add a register route method:

```
namespace GPC
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{Filtre}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some of the sites I've used, but nothing has worked for me:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Aug/15/IIS-Default-Documents-vs-ASPNET-MVC-Routes

[cannot set Default route for MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987078/cannot-set-default-route-for-mvc-project)

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/editing-routes-in-mvc

I'd appreciate if someone could show me how to get ABC.mycompany.com/Home/InstrumentList to show when the user goes to ABC.mycompany.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but your `RegisterRoutes` method should be in `RouteConfig` class that by default should be in `App_Start` foulder of MVC project. **This is not a method in `MvcApplication` class that located in `Global.asax.cs`** as i see in your question.

Then you should only change `RegisterRoutes` method like this to set different default controller action:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
     routes.MapRoute(
     "Default",
     "{controller}/{action}/{Filtre}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "InstrumentList", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfectly.  The sites I looked at either had this in global.asax.cs or didn't mention where it went.  Couple of questions, if you don't mind: 1.  Can I assume that the server is trying to get the "Default" page (default.aspx or something like that) and that this code re-routes Default.aspx to Home/InstrumentList?  2.  As I said, I found multiple conflicting answers when searching for this.  Can you recommend a source that explains things like this?  It seems like the default route would be a very elementary thing to know, but I couldn't figure out how to set it anywhere.

Comment: well, i also don't know this problem in deap. But i know that MVC Routing working over IIS default start page settings. All i know that iis setting writes something in Web.Config and default page is part of ASP.NET WebForms framework i gess. And it's ignored by MVC.